# Google Play Store rejection for default SMS app

Tags: android

The app that i am working on intends to be the default SMS app. As such the app prompts the dialog for becoming the default SMS app. Then it goes on to prompt for more permissions

> - Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> - Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
> - Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
> - Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
> - Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

I also request for SMS permissions

- Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
- Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
- Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS,
- Manifest.permission.READ_SMS

but these do not come up. I guess they are auto automatically granted once your app is accepted to be the default permission app.

The problem is that the app is getting rejected. I have tried changing the sequence of permission asked but does not help.
All i get is the following response.

[image]

**Tried uploading a video too, but got rejected again.

Given them a username to login and check the app, got rejected.

Can anyone point out where am i going wrong?**

Follow are the sequence of events happening in the app, if that helps. After the registration screen, app goes to the main screen with all SMS.

[image]

Comment: have you submit the request form?

Comment: I had face the same problem once i submit the form the error has gone forever.

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan what form is it. I don't remember filling up any form. Do you have a link?

Comment: You may have received it via Mail.

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan The request form is now part of apk submission. I am already doing it.

Comment: We had a similar problem and luckily were able to resolve this by chatting with google play support team. If you go to your play developer console then you can find help icon in Top right next to notification icon. You can contact their support team through there. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The dev community has been up in arms about this for months now. You're totally at the mercy of Google's bots. And what they decide is woefully inconsistent:

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/search?q=sms+permission&restrict_sr=on&include_over_18=on

Answer (score 0):

Permission Declaration Form :

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/closedform

Fill this form and resubmit

Note: Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by 9 January 2019 may be removed from Google Play.

Comment: Google play restricts the use of SMS and Call permissions.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303